# Nuxt not letting me route back when using require on source attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am able to view the image but when I try to navigate back with `<NuxtLink :to="{ path: 'About', hash: '#secondNav' }" class="close">` I get an error that says `Cannot find module './undefined.jpg'`

```
 "<template>
    <div class="container-fluid imgBackground vh-100">
        <div class="imgCont">
            <NuxtLink :to="{ path: 'About', hash: '#secondNav' }" class="close">
                <img
                    id="closeImg"
                    src="@/assets/images/closeHover.png"
                    src2="@/assets/images/close.png"
                />
            </NuxtLink>
            <img
                class="img-fluid"
                :src="imageUrl.myImg"
                alt="Sarah Project Image"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        imageUrl() {
            return {
                myImg: require(`@/assets/images/gallery/${this.$route.params.img}.jpg`)
            };
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use require or the assets folder for images using Nuxt.

[Nuxt provides a special folder](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/static/) called `static`.

Anything within this folder is mapped to the root of the domain.

Say for you have the domain example.com.

In your static folder you have:

- logo.png
- folder/image.jpg

Both of those would be mapped as follows:

- example.com/logo.png
- example.com/folder/image.jpg

To apply this to your requirement, you could put your `images` folder inside Nuxt's `static` folder.

Then in your computed method you'd simply format it like this:

```
imageUrl() {
    return `/images/gallery/${this.route.params.img}.jpg`;
}
```

and access it like this:

```
<img
    class="img-fluid"
    :src="imageUrl"
    alt="Sarah Project Image"
 />
```